# Fuse/OSGi Bundles and Dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, osgi, bundle

Good localtime community,

First a disclaimer, I am a greenhorn when it comes to Maven and OSGi, though I have read through half a dozen threads on the subject here. We are migrating from our current RESTful architecture to Apache's Fuse (ESB) and of course this requires us to sort out our dependencies and carefully craft our POMS for each bundle/container. Generally speaking each container will contain 3 in-house dependency bundles:

1. The container specific bundle which requires the next two in house bundles).
2. A processing bundle that all of our in-house containers will require (though they might require different versions), and which requires the bundle below.
3. A utility bundle that all of our containers will require (though they might require different versions).

Additionally each container can require one or more (and possibly up to over 100) third party jars, which are often reused between containers (though again no guarantee if versions will be the same).

We have (or will soon have) profiles for each container and for the ESB as a whole. What I would like to know is:

1. What is the best (cleanest) way to reuse third party jars between containers when we can?
2. I've read that we should never use  if we can avoid it, but we are heading down to jarmageddon when we try to explicitly import the jars/packages we need for our three bundles. I have read that *;resolution:=optional is not the way to go either (and for what it's worth, that doesn't seem to work for us anyway). Any thoughts?
3. I read on some forums that bundling third party jars is the way to go (though that seems a little overboard), and I have read on others that would kind of defeat the purpose of OSGi. Any thoughts there?
4. Our in-house bundles often require many of the same third party jars/versions. Is this simply a matter of building/installing our bundles in the correct order (utility, processing, and container specific) and exporting jars that can be reused by the next bundle(s)?

We are in a position where we can get our container working if we do some things we do not want to do (export everything, import *), but we'd like to handle this as cleanly as possible since we will have to repeat the process for many containers (with increasing dependencies) and since we will have to live with supporting/updating our implementation.

Thanks in advance for your guidance.